# PHP mySQL sanity check, query error

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to do a simple insert, and this one line is giving me issues. I can't for the life of me see whats wrong with it. So its gotta be something superbly simple that I need another pair of eyes to notice for me apparently.

`mysql_query("INSERT INTO ".MLIST."(email, when) VALUES('".mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email'])."', '".$timeNow."')") or die(mysql_error());`

the error is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near ''email', 'when') VALUES('me@domain.com', '2012-06-11
>   03:58:55')' at line 1

Comment: As stated in the PHP manual for the [`mysql_query()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) function: *Use of this extension is discouraged. Instead, the [MySQLi](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO_MySQL](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php) extension should be used. See also [MySQL: choosing an API](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) guide and [related FAQ](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated) for more information.*

Comment: Where are the single quotes around `'email'` and `'when'` coming from? Certainly not from the code you posted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`WHEN` is a keyword - place it inside backticks:

```
INSERT INTO ... (`email`, `when`) ...
```

Comment: thats exactly it.. been a while since i used the actual mysql_... functions been spoiled y ORMs i guess, thank you for pointing that out

Answer (score 0):

From my experience, I used to get this error even my SQL syntax is right. After checking for what causes the problem, I found my fault at another page which sends the data to the page I'm standing on.